# Can I Inline static method call to EF query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a query:

```
return from smi in context.Smis
       join smiInSegment in context.SmisInSegments on smi.Id equals smiInSegment.SmiId into smiToSmiInSegmentsJoin
       from smiInSegment in smiToSmiInSegmentsJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new SmiDtoInSegment
                               {
                                   SmiDto = new SmiDto
                                            {
                                                .....
                                            },
                                   SmiInSegment = smiInSegment
                               };
                }
```

And I have a builder class

```
internal static class SmiBuilder{

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static SmiDto CreateSmiDto(this Smi smi)
        {
            return new SmiDto
            {
                .....
            };
        }
}
```

But, when I use like this:

```
select new SmiDtoInSegment {
                               SmiDto = smi.CreateSmiDto(),
                               SmiInSegment = smiInSegment
                           };
```

it throws NotSupportedException:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Cat.DataAccess.Contracts.Dto.SmiDto CreateSmiDto(Cat.Data.Smi)' method

Using without Extension method lead to same result

So, Inlining doesn't work for some reasons? or this way cannot be used with EF query ?

Comment: You can't expect the JIT compiler to inline its compiled code into a query (which is what you appear to be assuming.. when was the last time you saw some Assembly opcodes in a query?). What you want is an expression visitor that builds a proper expression tree based on your custom method. Exactly how is unknown.. since you don't provide the body of the method.

Comment: LINQ to SQL did support a user-code projection if it was the last thing the query did. A very common scenario and a useful feature. EF still has not caught up with L2S.

Comment: Hm.. I thought, that C# Compiler just inlining body, without method call, but, it seems that JIT Compiler decide what to do. And it has some limitations [Aggressive Inlining in the CLR 4.5 JIT](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aggressive-inlining-clr-45-jit), one thing that I can see is "Methods larger than 32 bytes of IL", but can't count my body method, it's just 12 parameters assignments. I assume, if compiler just replace call method with body, then for linq2sql query it will not be matter, because, if i do it by myself, everything work perfect.

Comment: @usr You mean that this could be a feature for EF, but, why this doesn't work with inlining method body by Jit Compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the JIT does is invisible to .NET code. EF is a normal CLR assembly, it has no special CLR hooks or abilities. For this reason your theory cannot be true. The JIT cannot possibly help make this work because its effects are undetectable to user code.

To elaborate: EF has no way to inspect or analyze the body of CreateSmiDto. It cannot translate it to SQL.

LINQ to SQL *did* support a user-code projection if it was the last thing the query did. A very common scenario and a useful feature. EF still has not caught up with L2S. Your query would have just worked with L2S.

> So, Inlining doesn't work for some reasons?

I hope I have cleared up this misunderstanding. This has nothing to do with inlining.

> Or this way cannot be used with linq to sql ?

(You are using EF, not L2S.) No, this cannot be done in the current product version. [Vote for this user voice item.](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4560538-vastly-improve-linq-translation)

Comment: To elaborate: EF has no way to inspect or analyze the body of CreateSmiDto. It cannot translate it to SQL.

Comment: @cleric I assume that was a request to elaborate. Tell me how EF could find out what CreateSmiDto does? It must understand that to generate SQL.

Comment: sorry for 1-st comment. Here full version:

`To elaborate: EF has no way to inspect or analyze the body of CreateSmiDto. It cannot translate it to SQL.`
  
Yes, but why it can't make JIT Compiler? because attribute AggressiveInlining is for CLR. I assume, that if this call method could be inlined, then, for EF will not be call method more, and EF will make method body only.

Comment: Maybe you haven't yet heard about expression trees. EF analyzes an expression tree, not IL.

Comment: Yes, now, I've got it. Thank you! I didn't know about expression tree,  about their implementation. I still doesn't know enough, but that's the answer for my question, I think.

Answer (score -2):

Firts retrieve records from database with `ToList()`, then use `Select()`

```
return (from smi in context.Smis
   join smiInSegment in context.SmisInSegments on smi.Id equals smiInSegment.SmiId into smiToSmiInSegmentsJoin
   from smiInSegment in smiToSmiInSegmentsJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()).ToList()
   .Select(x => new SmiDtoInSegment {...});
```

Comment: There's no need to create an intermediate list here; this is what `AsEnumerable` is for.